# Defining predicates in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, predicate

Using prolog,

1. Define the predicate, conc(L1,L2,L3), where L3 is a concatenation of the two lists L1 and L2
2. Using above predicate, define the predicate One_after_first(X,L) is true iff item X occurs immediately after the first element in list L.

Comment: Run swi-prolog, enter `listing(append).` and it will *show* the definition of append/conc.

Answer (score 0):

```
conc(L1, L2, L3) :- append(L1, L2, L3).

one_after_first(L, Y) :- conc([_ | [Y | []]], _, L).
```

This solution uses `conc`, but there is an easier solution:

```
one_after_first([_ | [Y | _]], Y).
```

You can call it with:

```
one_after_first([1,2,3,4], 2).
```

Comment: Slightly nicer: `one_after_first([_, Y|_], Y).`